# Retrieving data from text file

Tags: c#, algorithm

My question is about getting continues data from text file. This is the description of the problem:

My requirement is to save each line in a text file. This text file is feeded in unknown intervals by external sources. Also, and most important - when the file reaches amount of 100 lines (for instance) it archives these lines in an unreachable source and clear its content.

Consider the situation where a listener peek at the file and see it contains 10 lines, the listener will take these lines and save them. Then after delta time (1 second, for instance) it peeks again and sees 93 lines. It saves the 83 that were unrecorded  as well.
Now, when the listener peeks for the third time it sees 3 lines. It obviously saves them, but notice that there is a miss of 7 lines (indexed 94-100)  that were not recorded by the listener.

It looks like that peeking at constant delta will not ensure that a miss wont happen.

How would you suggest is the best way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: try node js with you c# web app

Comment: A `FileSystemWatcher` might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to take data line by line from file and save it to database>>

```
 string line;
            string[] subLine;
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            try
            {
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    StreamReader inputData = new StreamReader(file);
                    const int maxRecords = 500;
                    int actualRecords = 0;
                    while ((line = inputData.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        subLine = line.Split(',');

                        try
                        {


                            string unknown = "unknown Fileld";
                            con.Open();
                            // int j=subLine.Length;
                            //for(int i=0;i<subLine.Length;i++)
                            if (actualRecords < maxRecords)
                            {
                                int i = 0;
                                //int j=subLine.Length;
                                //int index=subLine.Length-j;

                               // SQL= "insert into tradeFile values('" + ID + "','" + subLine[i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + unknown + "')";

                                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tradeFile values('" + subLine[i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + unknown + "')", con);
                                // cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into tradeFile values('" + subLine[i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + unknown + "')", con);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                actualRecords++;
                                //  j--;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int i = 0;
                                //int j=subLine.Length;
                                //int index=subLine.Length-j;
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tradeFile values('" + subLine[i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + unknown + "')", con);
                                //cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into tradeFile values('" + subLine[i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + subLine[++i].ToString() + "','" + unknown + "')", con);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                actualRecords = 0;
                            }





                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }
                        //counter++;
                    }
                    inputData.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Hope you will apply further logic and it will prove helpful to you.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer..pay attention that is does not apply to the problem i intreduced buy thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

For more different File operation Details Click here

[File Operations in C#](http://niharstechnicalfunda.blogspot.in/2013/03/file-operations-in-c-net.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could hold the lines in some form of collection, such as `List<string>` and validating the `List1.Add(line)` against the capacity of the collection (100 for instance) using a while or if statement, `while(count < capactity)`

If you have read/write access to the file, you could remove the lines after adding them to the collection.